# How to add a link under plugin title in plugins page in dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I want to add a custom link here:

[image]

beside "Auto-Updates Disabled" I want to write "Custom Plugins" and add a link to a page. Is there a hook I can use to add a link there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Plugins Page uses an object of WP_Plugins_List_Table, which extends the class WP_List_Table. The "View"-Links are built using the method "views", which conveniently uses the Filter `views_{$this->screen->id}` .

To add your own link to this list, you put a filter on "views_plugins" like this:

```
add_filter('views_plugins', 'wpse_415866_add_plugins_view');
function wpse_415866_add_plugins_view( $views ){
    $views['my-custom-view-link'] = '<a href="https://my-awesome-website.com">My Awesome Website</a>';
    return $views;
}
```

I didn't test this, but it should work.

Happy Coding!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks